# CocoaPods - Install Failed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

when I'm trying to install cocoa pods i get this error :

```
gem install cocoapods -V
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Host is down - connect(2)        
(https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

im also installed the latest version of Command-Line-Tools and Xcode

im not using any proxies !

is there any other methods of installing cocapods?

Comment: May be Proxy blocking?

Answer (score 1):

Try many times. It will end up working.